# why i ld Apache Arrow failed when i change CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to "/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/bin/g++" in cmake?

Tags: c++, apache-arrow, apache-arrow-cpp

When I use gcc 10.3 (but the c++ library file is /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/), I use cmake to compile the project with the <arrow/api.h> header file normally, but this inlucde is too old , so I used `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/bin/g++`, but this caused me to get an ld error when using the last step of `make`, and a lot of errors similar to the following.
`/usr/local/include/arrow/result.h:133: undefined reference to`arrow::Status::ToString() const'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/ld: /usr/local/include/arrow/result.h:132: undefined reference to `arrow::internal::DieWithMessage(std::string const&)'`

i trid to scl_source enable devtoolset-10 and install arrow, but it seems nonting happened. i am confused which part of operation is wrong, gcc, include path or arrow path? or cmakelists.txt?
Please help me to fix the problem, thank you.

Comment: Moving from GCC 4.8 to GCC 10 makes me think you were hit by the CXX11 ABI change. Recompile _everything_ (application *and* apache arrow) with the same compiler.